# how to connect sql to php

Tags: php, sql, sql-server-2005

I had connect sql to php but it shows error

> Call to undefined function mssql_connect()

```
<?php
  $myServer = "sql";
  $myUser = "ste";
  $myPass = "the";
  $myDB = "SQL2005"; 
  $dbhandle = mssql_connect($myServer, $myUser, $myPass)
  or die("Couldn't connect to SQL Server on $myServer"); 
?>
```

Comment: Is this from a Linux or Windows system?

Answer (score 1):

According to [the documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/intro.mssql.php), the MS SQL extension you are trying to use is no longer supported and you should use an alternative.

Answer (score 0):

`mssql_connect`

Appears to be a typo

Comment: its the same dude, where do you see typo..!

Comment: I guess it would depend upon what SQL server is running.

Answer (score 0):

Check your `phpinfo()` and make sure the `mssql` extension is enabled. See [PHP.net](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mssql.php)

Answer (score 0):

in your "php.ini", search for

```
extension=php_mssql.dll
```

and uncoment if its already commented. Then check if you can get it working.

Answer (score 0):

The following link should help you to resolve this: http://www.phpfreaks.com/forums/index.php?topic=197064.0

Specifically:

> For the mssql extension to work, all of the 
>   following must be true -
>
> The php.ini that you are changing must be the one that php is using.
>
> The php_mssql.dll must be in the ext folder.
>
> The extension_dir setting in php.ini must be set to the ext folder,
>   something like  extension_dir = c:\php\ext
>
> To get changes made to php.ini to take effect, you must stop and start
>   the IIS web service. Do this in the services control panel or reboot
>   your computer. Just stopping and starting the web site in the IIS
>   management console is not enough.
>
> mssql requires: ntwdblib.dll to be available on the Windows PATH. It
>   is better to add the php folder to the Windows PATH instead of moving
>   any files around. Re-logon or reboot your computer to get any changes
>   made to the Windows PATH statement to take effect.
>
> The php folder must have proper permissions set to allow the IIS user
>   account to read the files in the php folder and in the ext folder.

This: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mssql-connect.php is the documentation for mssql_connect() also which may help.

Answer (score 0):

hey check whether the php_mssql.dll file is present at wamp\php\ext location or not.